# Alterations with a integer in c++

Tags: c++

This is easy for you. I am busy with a test using c++. I have 2 values:

```
0 and 1
```

I can find random number between. Now i want to alternate between them. If i get "1" in step one then in step two I want to get "0" and in step three "1" again where it alternate

```
step1 = 1
step2 = 0
step3 = 1
step4 = 0
```

I tried increment and decrements

```
  int value;
  if(value == 0)
  {   
      value = value + 1;
  }
  else if(value == 1)
  {
      value = value -1;
  }
```

This code does not work. If it sees a 0 it will become 1 but the next step the value will be 1 again.

Comment: You mean that there are series of steps, and in first step if you get 1, then in next step you get zero, and then 1 again, and so on?

Comment: Aw, you're not initializing `value` :(

Comment: What does the "string" from the title refer to?

Comment: @jrok Depends on the compiler, some will initialize to zero.

Comment: It is initialized when i run application with    cin >> value;

Comment: @grieve, it is officially undefined.  Some compilers *do* define the behavior, but it's generally not a good idea to rely on that.  It caused a security vulnerability in OpenSLL not too long ago (see also http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html , http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know_14.html , http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know_21.html , https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/EXP33-C.+Do+not+reference+uninitialized+memory )

Comment: @MaxLybbert Agreed that you should not rely on it, just pointing out that it may be initialized to zero depending on the compiler you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really only ever need 0 and 1:

```
unsigned int value = 0;

while (1) {
   value = (value + 1) & 1;
   // do whatever is needed with value;
}
```

This works because in binary 0 + 1 = 1, and 1 + 1 = 10. The '& 1' portion tells us to always take the last bit.

Comment: @David uint is short hand for unsigned int. It was not a typo of unit. :)

Comment: C++ defines no such type as uint. Must be unsigned int?

Comment: @grieve sorry, I made a typo. I meant what was `uint` not `unit`. lol

Comment: @UnderDog Fixed. In my C++ code we had defined it, and I just got lazy in using it here.

Answer (score 1):

Wild guess: You are using floating point types (`double`or `float`) to represent those numbers. You can't compare those types using the `==` operator, you need to take their precision into account.

Take a look at this question on [how to compare floating point types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17333/most-effective-way-for-float-and-double-comparison).

Comment: No i am not using floats or doubles

Comment: So by saying "I can find random number between 0 and 1" you mean "randomly 0 or 1"?

Comment: That i can do with rand()%2, i'm trying to alternate between 0 and 1. Like if i get 1 in a step then in the next step i get 0 and next step 1 again

Comment: I was only trying to say, that e.g. 0.5 is also "between 0 and 1". Thats what initially confused me ;)

Answer (score 1):

put in a bool switch with your if statements, eg

```
bool firstHit = false;
if(value == 0 && firstHit == false)
{   
  value = value + 1;
  firstHit = true;
}
else if(value == 1 &&firstHit == true)
{
  value = value -1;
  firstHit = false;
}
```

Comment: How exactly is an extra, redundant, variable going to help?

Comment: I think you're missing the fact that the second part is **else** if. The intent would become more clear if it was just if.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine dude. I tested it, and its working.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{

    int value=1; //Say first step

  for (int i=0 ; i <= 10; i++ )
{
    if(value==0)
    {
        value=value+1;
    }
    else if (value==1)
    {
        value=value-1;
    }
         cout << "Step "<<i<<": "<<value<<"\n";
}

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: @JohanDela, And what *is* your compiler? Note that this `value` is initialized, too.

Answer (score 1):

The code you're showing doesn't initialize `value` to anything.

Other than that,

```
if(value == 0)
  {   
      value = value + 1;
  }
  else if(value == 1)
  {
      value = value -1;
  }
```

This looks like it should work fine if you just want to alternate between 1 & 0, as it will switch it every time you iterate through it.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest  :

```
value = 1 - value;
```

There's a `<g>` before the colon, but the system software seems to not want to display it.